# Fit Exponentially modified Gaussian to 2D data

Tags: r, curve-fitting, gaussian

I am trying to fit a exponentially modified gaussian (like in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentially_modified_Gaussian_distribution equation (1)) to my 2D (x, y) data in R.

My data are:

```
x <- c(1.13669371604919, 1.14107275009155, 1.14545404911041, 1.14983117580414, 
1.15421032905579, 1.15859162807465, 1.16296875476837, 1.16734790802002, 
1.17172694206238, 1.17610621452332, 1.18048334121704, 1.18486452102661, 
1.18924164772034, 1.19362080097198, 1.19800209999084, 1.20237922668457, 
1.20675826072693, 1.21113955974579, 1.21551668643951, 1.21989583969116, 
1.22427713871002, 1.22865414619446, 1.2330334186554, 1.23741245269775, 
1.24178957939148, 1.24616885185242, 1.25055003166199, 1.25492715835571, 
1.25930631160736, 1.26368761062622, 1.26806473731995, 1.2724437713623
)
y <- c(42384.03125, 65262.62890625, 235535.828125, 758616, 1691651.75, 
    3956937.25, 8939261, 20311304, 41061724, 65143896, 72517440, 
    96397368, 93956264, 87773568, 82922064, 67289832, 52540768, 50410896, 
    35995212, 27459486, 14173627, 12645145, 10069048, 4290783.5, 
    2999174.5, 2759047.5, 1610762.625, 1514802, 958150.6875, 593638.6875, 
    368925.8125, 172826.921875)
```

The function I am trying to fit and the value I am trying to minimize for optimization:

```
EMGCurve <- function(x, par)
{
  ta <- 1/par[1]
  mu <- par[2]
  si <- par[3]
  h <- par[4]
  Fct.V <- (h * si / ta) * (pi/2)^0.5 * exp(0.5 * (si / ta)^2 - (x - mu)/ta)
  Fct.V
}

RMSE <- function(par)
{ 
  Fct.V <- EMGCurve(x,par)
  sqrt(sum((signal - Fct.V)^2)/length(signal))
}

result <- optim(c(1, x[which.max(y)], unname(quantile(x)[4]-quantile(x)[2]), max(y)), 
                lower = c(1, min(x), 0.0001, 0.1*max(y)),
                upper = c(Inf, max(x), 0.5*(max(x) - min(x)), max(y)),
                RMSE, method="L-BFGS-B", control=list(factr=1e7))
```

However, when I try to vizualize the result in the end it seems like nothing usful is happening,..

```
plot(x,y,xlab="RT/min",ylab="I")
lines(seq(min(x),max(x),length=1000),GaussCurve(seq(min(x),max(x),length=1000),result$par),col=2)
```

However, for some reason it doesn't work at all, although a managed to do it for a normal distribution with similar code. Would be great if someone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it might be of some use, I got an OK fit to your data using an X-shifted log-normal type peak equation, "y = a * exp(-0.5 * pow((log(x-d)-b) / c, 2.0))" with parameters a = 9.4159743234392539E+07, b = -2.7516932481669185E+00, c = -2.4343893243720971E-01, and d = 1.1251623071481867E+00 yielding  R-squared = 0.994 and RMSE = 2.49E06. I personally was unable to fit using the equation in your post. There may be value in scaling the dependent data as the values seem large, but this equation seems to fit the data as is.
[image: peak]

Comment: Thank you a lot, I will try it out with this fit! Is the problem maybe that I didn't use the error function (as given in wikipedia for the equation). I left it our because I didn't understand what it was or know how I could deal with it...

Comment: Meh - I just fit the data, nothing special, and used the usual lowest-sum-of-squared-error most people use when curve fitting.

Comment: Thanks that worked :) Is there an efficient way to estimate the parameters for this function from the row data? I get where "a" and "d" are coming from,.. but not the other two...

Comment: I used my open source Python online curve and surface fitter zunzun.com, which has a genetic algorithm named Differential Evolution to estimate initial parameter values. Specifically, I simply pasted the data into the "text data editor" at http://zunzun.com/Equation/2/Peak/Log-Normal%20Peak%20A%20Shifted/ and hit the submit button.